# How to change the NTP servers that the VMware Esxi hypervisor uses?

Tags: command-line, vmware, ntpd

I am trying to change the `NTP` servers that the `VMware Esxi hypervisor` uses.

The system I am using is:

```
[root@machine:~] esxcli system version get
   Product: VMware ESXi
   Version: 6.0.0
   Build: Releasebuild-7967664
   Update: 3
   Patch: 84
```

I ran the commands below:

```
[root@machine:~] ps | grep ntp
21974404  21974404  ntpd
```

=> The `ntpd` service is running.

```
[root@machine:~] cat /etc/ntp.conf
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict default kod nomodify notrap noquery
driftfile /etc/ntp.drift
server 0.pool.ntp.org
server 1.pool.ntp.org
server 2.pool.ntp.org
```

=> I added the last three lines to `/etc/ntp.conf`.

```
[root@machine:~] /etc/init.d/ntpd  restart
Stopping ntpd
watchdog-ntpd: Terminating watchdog process with PID 21974394
Starting ntpd
```

=> I restarted the `ntpd` service.

```
[root@machine:~] ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 halmahera.ordim .INIT.          16 u    -  128    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 orb.pstam.ovh   .INIT.          16 u    -  128    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
 likho.oneyed.mo .INIT.          16 u    -  128    0    0.000    0.000   0.000
```

=> Despite the fact that I added the `{0, 1, 2}.pool.ntp.org servers` in `/etc/ntp.conf`, it doesn't seem like the NTP servers have actually been replaced.

Can you help me change these servers?

Best regards.

EDIT 1

```
[root@machine:~] ps aux | grep ntpd
ps: no non-option arguments
ps
    -C           Display only cartels
    -P           Display PCID
    -T           Display used time
    -c           Display verbose command line
    -g           Display session ID and process group
    -i           Display summary information
    -j           Display GID
    -n           Display nChildren (only with --tree)
    -N           Display nThreads  (only with --tree)
    -s           Display state
    -t           Display type
    -u           Display only userworlds
    -U [N]       Display [only] userspace ID
    -v           Display non truncated values
    -Z           Display the security domain
    -z           Display zombie cartels
    -J or --tree Display userworlds in a tree layout

[root@machine:~] ntpq -c rv
ntpq: read: Connection refused
```

Comment: Please include the output of `ps aux | grep ntpd` and `ntpq -c rv` which will run the `c`ommand "`r`ead `v`ariables" which might give some useful output for troubleshooting.

Comment: @pzkpfw - Thanks. I edited my post.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't want to change them through the web management interface?

Comment: Names like `0.pool.ntp.org` are a sort of alias, and get converted to an ip address that is near you. This ip address is then looked up by ntpq and you see the real hostname for that ip. You shouldn't expect to see `0.pool.ntp.org` . Use the `host` command to convert an ip address to a hostname, and a hostname or alias to a list of ip addresses.